# Drawing feature on static image map is not persistent in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have created map with static images in OpenLayers. Now I am trying to draw features on top of my static images. I am able to draw the features but once I move out my mouse from image, drawing is getting disappeared. I wanted to draw the features and make it persistent. Below is my code:

HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dicom Image</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
       body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #212529;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .ol-viewport,
        .ol-unselectable {
            display: block !important;
        }

        .ol-scale-line {
            bottom: 200px !important;
            left: 600px !important;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }

        .ol-scale-line-inner {
            width: 300px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        .ol-attribution.ol-uncollapsible {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .conrol-buttons {
            margin: 10px 5px;
            padding: 7px 10px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            /* font-weight: bold; */
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            height: 1.8em;
            /* width: 1.375em; */
            line-height: .4em;
            background-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, .75);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 60, 136, 1);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        code {
            font-size: 87.5%;
            color: #e83e8c;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
        code,
        kbd,
        pre,
        samp {
            font-family: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        .controls {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="controls">
        <!--<p>To activate freehand drawing for lines, polygons, and circles, hold the <code>Shift</code> key. To remove the
            last point of a
            line or polygon, press "Undo".</p> -->
        <input class="conrol-buttons" type="button" value="Point" id="Point">
        <input class="conrol-buttons" type="button" value="LineString" id="LineString">
        <input class="conrol-buttons" type="button" value="Polygon" id="Polygon">
        <input class="conrol-buttons" type="button" value="Circle" id="Circle">
        <input class="conrol-buttons" type="button" value="Undo" id="undo">
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js code:

```
import './style.css';
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import View from "ol/View.js";
import { Projection } from "ol/proj.js";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent.js";
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import img from "./dicomImg.js";
import { Tile as TileLayer } from "ol/layer.js";
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import { ScaleLine, defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';
import { DragRotateAndZoom, defaults as defaultInteractions} from 'ol/interaction';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw';

var scaleline = new ScaleLine({
    units: 'imperial',
});

var source = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });

var imgArray = [img.i0, img.i1, img.i2, img.i3, img.i4, img.i5, img.i6, img.i7, img.i8, img.i9, 
    img.i10, img.i11, img.i12, img.i13, img.i14, img.i15, img.i16, img.i17, img.i18, img.i19,
];

var imageSize = [512, 512];
var extent = [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]];
var projection = new Projection({
  code: "custom-image",
  units: "pixels",
  extent: extent
});

var raster = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
});

var source = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });

var vector = new VectorLayer({
    source: source,
});

vector.setZIndex(999);

var layers = [];
layers.push(raster);
layers.push(vector);
for (var i=0; i< imgArray.length; i++){
    layers.push(new ImageLayer({
        source: new Static({
            url: imgArray[i], 
            projection: projection,
            imageExtent: [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]]
        }),
        zIndex: i,
    }));
}
//layers.push(roaster);
//layers.push(vector);

var map = new Map({
    interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new DragRotateAndZoom()]),
    controls: defaultControls().extend([scaleline]),
    layers: layers,
    target: "map", 
    view: new View({
        projection: projection,
        center: getCenter(extent),
        resolution: 1,
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 8
    }),
});

map.addControl(scaleline);

//var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction(interactionValue) {
    var value = interactionValue;
    if (value !== 'None') {
        draw = new Draw({
            source: source,
            type: value,
        });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
}


addInteraction('LineString');

document.getElementById('Point').addEventListener('click', function (){
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction('Point');
});

document.getElementById('LineString').addEventListener('click', function (){
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction('LineString');
});

document.getElementById('Polygon').addEventListener('click', function (){
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction('Polygon');
});

document.getElementById('Circle').addEventListener('click', function (){
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction('Circle');
});

document.getElementById('undo').addEventListener('click', function () {
    draw.removeLastPoint();
});
```

Comment: Your `vector` layer, where drawn features are placed, gets covered by image layers. Just set `zIndex` option of `vector` layer to a value that is higher than `zIndex` value of any image layer.

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM after adding the zIndex in Vector Layer. Drawing are getting persistent.

Comment: @rakesh can you share the code snippet where you added the zindex over the vector layer

Comment: @Yusuf - Have added line of the code  "vector.setZIndex(999);" in the main.js. You can refer whole code above.